# SAP ABAP DCL change the cardinality of the CDS VIEW result?

Tags: abap, sap-erp, cds

I have a CDS view `ZCDS_XXX` :

```
define view ZCDS_XXX
  as select distinct from XXX 
association [1..*] to ZCDS_YYY as _YYY ...
{
  key a,
  _YYY
} ...
```

I have a  DCL `ZDCL_XXX` :

```
define role ZDCL_XXX{
  grant
    select
      on
        ZCDS_XXX
          where
            ( _YYY.ProfitCenter ) = aspect pfcg_auth( K_PCAR_REP, PRCTR );
}
```

> The goal is to return the entries of the CDS `ZCDS_XXX`
> for which the user has at least one authorization from a list of associated profit centers .

---

Okay everything is working fine ...

**BUT**, when the DCL is active, The *CDS* view `ZCDS_XXX` view returns me duplicate keys
despite the `DISTINCT` (removes duplicates from the results list).
As if the DCL does the processing after the selection and
changed the cardinality of my result >(

---

I would like to know if there is a solution directly in the *DCL* or the *CDS* view to avoid having duplicates and avoid doing a `SELECT DISTINCT` in *oSQL* or delete duplicates for example if I use the *CDS* view in a search help.

And also if you have a link that describes its behavior or the *SQL* syntax in the *DCL*, I can't find much in the docs...

Thanks you a lot for your help !

Comment: So putting a DCL which checks fields from the association results in the association always getting expanded even if none of its fields are requested? That's an interesting gotcha.

Comment: Mhm it's weird actually it seems to be more complicated.
I redid the example with a simple association and the association
 with an area to be controlled by authorization that includes different values ​​and the association is not consumed by the DCL and everything is fine.

So it may come from my association which has several joints etc. I'll try to find the moment when everything goes crazy

Comment: IIRC this case can only occur when the cardinality in the CDS entity missmatches the data, i.e. when the association states [1..1] but there are actually multiple entries

Comment: The DCL gets mixed into the SQL query sent to the database, thus when the DCL makes incorrect assumptions about the underlying datamodel, so does the SQL query, producing potentially unexpected results

Comment: Documentation can be found in https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_cp_index_htm/CLOUD/en-US/index.htm?file=abencds_f1_cond_pfcg_mapping.htm

Comment: what is the primary key of `ZCDS_YYY`? does it match with the key of `ZCDS_XXX`? you don't give the full view definition so we don't know on which field you associate them, and by which field you make a conclusion of *key duplication*

Comment: also Jonas assumption `CDS entity missmatches the data` makes sense, as we don't see dataset samples which gets duplicated

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need a left outer to one join in the CDS definition, please give it a try.
At SQL run time of a CDS selection, cardinality plays a important role if using a field from associated entity. Please read this blog for the general explanation  https://blogs.sap.com/2018/08/20/cardinality-of-association-in-cds-view/